# Autoload .Xresources when system is started

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, ubuntu-12.04

How can I load the settings from `~/.Xresources` when system is loaded?
Currently, I write

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

everytime I start the system and I'd like to automate it somehow.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with LightDM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's automatically read by some DMs, but in your case, you can add the following command to your `~/.initrc` so that it's executed at each session start:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

The first part ensures that you won't get an error if you decide to delete `.Xresources` in the future, and the `-merge` option allows you to add your custom properties to the ones that can have been previously defined, instead of replacing the whole set.

If this still doesn't do, try creating a `~/.xprofile` file that contains the following line: `USRRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's because I use LightDM which doesn't read `.initrc` I'm not sure.

Comment: That's just weird, LightDM is supposed to read and merge .Xresources automatically. What are the permissions? Are you sure the name is correct?

Comment: Yes, the name is correct and permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`. I also tried to change permissions to 777 (`sudo chmod 777 ~/.Xresources`) but without luck.

Comment: Hmm... found this bit on a forum: create a `~/.xprofile` file that contains the following:
`USRRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources`